# How to split string in 3 characters and keep on appending in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I have requirement to implement search suggestion in JMeter script like given below,
let say i have string iPhone then requests in JMeter should be like this

How to write logic to split string (iPhone) like iPh, iPho, iPhon, iPhone?

https://example.com?q=iPh

https://example.com?q=iPho

https://example.com?q=iPhon

https://example.com?q=iPhone

How can i implement this in JMeter script, first Hit will be after 3 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
def string = 'iPhone'

0.upto(string.length() - 3, index -> {
   if (index == 0) {
       vars.put('somevar_' + (index + 1), string.take(3))
   } else {
       vars.put('somevar_' + (index + 1), string.take(3 + index))
   }
})
```

should do the trick for you, it will produce the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

```
somevar_1=iPh
somevar_2=iPho
somevar_3=iPhon
somevar_4=iPhone
```

which can be iterated using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) like:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: if we have Search String like "Hello Word" with space between strings So requests should be like this.  



https://example.com?q=Hel  

https://example.com?q=Hell

https://example.com?q=Hello

here need to append + with next character wherever space is coming after first string.

https://example.com?q=Hello+W

https://example.com?q=Hello+Wo

https://example.com?q=Hello+Wor

https://example.com?q=Hello+Word